# Return value type for class member function

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

I have a couple of `A` like classes with method, say, `get_value()`, which return values of different types. And one class `B`, which returns a value with method `value()`. For example:

```
struct A_like1 {
    int get_value() const { return 10; }
};
struct A_like2 {
    char get_value() const { return 'a'; }
};
struct B
{
    float value() const { return 2.5; }
};
```

Now, I need a function to retrieve that value for these classes. I have a function:

```
template<typename T>
auto get_value(const T & t) -> result_of<decltype(&T::get_value)(T)>::type
{
    return t.get_value();
}
```

It gives me a number of compilation errors on VS2010 starting with:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'type'   c:\_data\work\vmxi\c++\vox\vox\template_specialization.h    51
```

For `B` I have an overload, which works fine. The question is, how to make `get_value()` work with `result_of<>()`?

P.S. Hmm, I have just realized that I could've used `-> decltype(T().get_value())` instead, which works fine. But why doesn't `result_of<>()` work? Besides, I was able to declare a variable in `.cpp` file:

```
result_of<decltype(&A_like1::get_value)(A_like1)>::type i=0;
```

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  If you have C++14 you don't need a trailing return type at all and just use `auto`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I assume he uses two templated functions with the same name, the one presented here to work with `A`-like classes and one to work with `B`-like classes. And then you need the trailing return type to trigger SFINAE.

Comment: @Corristo Ah yes.  I missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword [`typename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) can be used to declare that a dependent name, like `std::result_of<T>::type`, is a type. Otherwise, I believe it's assumed that `std::result_of<T>::type` is a data member. In C++14, several type traits have gotten a `using` alias that includes the `typename` keyword for you. These alias are always have the same name as the trait, with a `_t` suffix.

Try :

```
typename result_of<decltype(&T::get_value)(T)>::type
```

or, with C++14 :

```
result_of_t<decltype(&T::get_value)(T)>
```

Comment: How easy is this!! Thanks a bunch )