# How to get return type of class method?

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, type-traits, member-functions

I tried to use `std::result_of`, but could not manage it.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
public:
    int foo();
};

int main() 
{
    using return_type = std::result_of_t<Foo::foo()>; // error
    return 0;
}
```

So how can I get the return type of `Foo::foo`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike, it is not applicable as the answer is for functions and not class methods

Comment: Sorry, wrong link.  Correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716296/deduce-return-type-of-member-function

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398169/return-value-type-for-class-member-function

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the return type of `Foo::foo`?

You can use [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) as follows.

```
#include <type_traits>      // std::invoke_result_t

using return_type = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&Foo::foo), Foo>;
```

[See a demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/avov6E5PK)

Or using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

```
#include <utility>     // std::declval

using return_type = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().foo());
```

[See a demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n9PYob5nE)

---

**Side note**: The `std::result_of_t` is deprecated in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and removed in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). Therefore, your code bases have to update/ change, when you upgrade to C++20 in the future, in case you use it.  Read more:

[What is the reason for `std::result_of` deprecated in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021734/what-is-the-reason-for-stdresult-of-deprecated-in-c17)

Answer (score 0):

`Foo::foo()` is not a type, `std::result_of` expects a function type.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
 public:
  int foo();
};

int main() {
  using return_type = std::result_of<decltype(&Foo::foo)>;
  return 0;
}
```